# Sketching Semi-Cubical Graphs

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having trouble sketching these kind of graphs, for example, I have the equation:
$$(1-y_2^2)^3=\frac{9}{4}y_1^2$$

Note: the map is over the real numbers.

Could somebody please give me some advice on what is the best way to sketch a function such as this? (Also if I have named the type of equation incorrectly then please feel free to correct me!)

Many thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite $$(1-y_2^2)^3=\frac{9}{4}y_1^2$$

as  $$\pm\frac23\sqrt{(1-y_2^2)^3}=y_1$$

and then you can easily calculate the two $y_1$ values for each value of $y_2$ you choose.

When $1-y_2^2 < 0$ (and so $\lvert y_2\rvert > 1$)  there will be no $y_1$ values; when $1-y_2^2 = 0$ there will be only one.

Comment: Ah great, thank you very much!